# precision and recall on biased data set

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision-recall

Suppose a two class classification problem. One class has more than 95% of labelled data, and the other class has 5% of labelled data. The two class are very biased.

I am doing class validation to evaluate different classifiers, I found if a classifier intentionally to predict to the class which has majority (95%) label, even if the prediction result on other class is not accurate, from precision/recall, it is hard to distinguish since the other class has only 5% labelled data.

Here are the methods/metrics (using precision/recall) I am using. I am wondering if any other better metrics or method to evaluate considering the minor 5% class? I am assign a weight to the minor 5% class, but I ask here for a more systematic method to measure biased data set.

Using scikit learn + python 2.7.

```
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(bdt, X, Y, cv=10, scoring='recall_weighted')
print("Recall: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(bdt, X, Y, cv=10, scoring='precision_weighted')
print("Precision: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
```

Comment: Why do keep posting these types of question on SO? They belong on  http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Merlin, I can do to `stats`, thanks for the ideas. I just feel more experts here. :))

Comment: Since, you dont seem to get it. YOUR QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC ON STACKOVER. see link. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 4):

This is a common problem in statistics, thus you will find plenty of resources in the internet. Check, e.g., [8 Tactics To Combat Imbalanced Training Data](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/).

The probably easiest method is to resample your data. The simplest way would be to duplicate the minority class until both classes are equally represented.
A statistically more sound approach would be to first learn a probability distribution for reach of your classes, and then draw *n* samples for every class. Thus, you then have a balanced dataset.

This, of course, depends on your data - or simply learn only on an unbiased subset of your data.
See the article for more options.

Comment: Thanks Martin, what do you mean re-sample? If we use stratified sampling, still get majority of one class v.s. another.

Comment: Thanks Martin, do you know if there are any scikit learn solution for re-sampling based solution, such as "A statistically more sound approach would be to first learn a probability distribution for reach of your classes, and then draw n samples for every class"?

Comment: Another dumb question is, when scikit-learn calculate precision and recall (refer to my code above), it calculate average precision and recall of each class? Which means if prediction of one class has high precision/recall, the other class has relatively low precision/recall, the final results are still ok?

Comment: That's a different question, so does not belong here. Ask on [stats.SX]( stats.stackexchange.com). Also, I do not know scikit. I would suggest you to *first* learn basic machine learning fundamentals, *then* search for a suitable approach for your problem, *then* see how you can implement *your approach* in python using scikit. So: *first search for a statistical solution, then how to do it using scikit* —Not vice versa.

Comment: Thanks Martin, you mentioned "draw n samples for every class", I think we can do directly, why do we need to fit a distribution first?